# C++ Add non-virtual static method in interface is normal?

Tags: c++

I thought interface can only include pure virtual functions in C++. However, recently my college showed me the following code:

```cpp
class IAddition {
 public:

     virtual bool MethodA() = 0;

     static bool StaticMethodA(IAddition* interface) {
           return interface->MethodA();
     }

     static std::string GetStr() { 
         return "A";
     }
};
```

The interface can be compiled but I feel the code weird.  I can't understand what is a static method of an interface? Is this very normal in C++ programs?

Comment: c++ has no concept of an interface. There is only classes that may or may not have virtual methods

Comment: Perfectly normal to mix regular, virtual (pure or not) and static member functions, depending on need.

Comment: What's unusual is for `StaticMethodA` to be a static member.  It should be a friend, found via ADL.  Even more common would be friend overloaded operators defined for the interface, delegating to protected pure virtual member functions.

Comment: I'd go to the extent that, at some point, this will be the standard when you start working with templates.

Comment: Note that a static member function cannot be virtual, so "non-virtual static" in the title is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought interface can only include pure virtual functions in C++

There is no such requirement imposed by the C++ standard.

> Is this very normal in C++ programs?

Yes(assuming by normal you mean well-formed), this is a valid C++ program. We're allowed to use virtual member function with static as well as non-static member functions within a class.

Answer (score 0):

As `blankettripod` point out in comment and `Jason Liam` in other answear C++ language do not have interface concept. So purely from C++ standard perspective this is fine.

But in many best C++ practices interface means:

> class or a struct without any fields and only with public pure virtual functions inside (except for destructor which must be implemented and should be virtual).

See also [Cpp Core Guidelines I.25: Prefer empty abstract classes as interfaces to class hierarchies](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#i25-prefer-empty-abstract-classes-as-interfaces-to-class-hierarchies).

So your `IAddition` fails this definition because of this static methods.
Many developers will not have problem with that.
On other hand in many projects where coding standard rules are more strict and respected, this is no longer an interface and should be fixed. There are many rationales, for example if this API is ported to other languages (like Java or C# where interfaces are part of language features) this extra methods will be a real technical problem.